# "if" statement in c++ doesn't evaluate conditions from left to right

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, integer-division, divide-by-zero

I was referring to the question "*["IF" argument evaluation order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925479/if-argument-evaluation-order)*" for understanding the evaluation order for "if" statement in c++.

Here is the code where the conditions in if statements are evaluated in a wrong order.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t = 0;
    if((1 / t) == 1 && t != 0)
    {
        cout << "0" << endl;
    }

    cout << "1" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result is 1 instead of floating point exception.

Comment: So do you get a FP exception if you run `1/t` outside of an if?

Comment: yes, but not in the if condition

Comment: Have you checked generated assembly for that code? I'd guess compiler noticed that `t` is equal to `0` and skipped the condition altogether. Check again with `t` read from cin.

Comment: I suggest you use a different means to check the order of evaluation.

Comment: What compiler are you using? It is giving FP on GCC.

Comment: `if` doesn't have to evaluate its conditions (plural); it has **exactly one** condition. Now this expression may have sub-expressions, but that's not the concern of `if`. `if` only evaluates the outermost value, possibly converting it to `bool`.

Comment: I got FP exception on GCC without optimization. 
I got `1` with optimization. 
I think it's quite reasonable. You have no guarantee for the side-effect of devision. 
If the complier evaluates condition you get left-right evaluation and may get FP exception.
If the complier can remove the code you cannot get such side-effects like FP exception.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Division-by-zero is undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

[[expr.mul]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.mul#4)

> If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Indeed. In this godbolt example we can see that the entire `if` statement has been elided by the compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/YzZ-q8

Comment: @RichardHodges Not only that. If you replace `t != 0` in the `if` condition by `t == 0`, [the whole `main` function body disappears](https://godbolt.org/z/3bEx1f). We really can't make any assumption on UB.

Answer (score 6):

divide by zero doesn't guarantee that every time program will throw you a runtime error. this is why dividing by zero is an undefined behaviour.

as C standard states;

> The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is zero, the behaviour is undefined.

as for C++ (03-5.6.4);

> The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator yields the remainder from the division
>   of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined; otherwise
>   (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a. If both operands are nonnegative then the remainder is nonnegative;
>   if not, the sign of the remainder is implementation-defined

Comment: This is C++, not C. The text in the C++ spec is probably the same, but your answer refers to C instead of C++.

Comment: @Mast my answer refers to c and c++ although I admit the c standard is quoted

Comment: Yes, so I'd suggest changing the text to include C++.