# Checking null pointer && pointer->member value in the same if statement

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This is a pretty basic question, but I could not find a clear answer:
is it allowed to check that a pointer is not null and (&&) to also check one of its members value in the same if statement?

Rephrased: is the right part of the condition in the example below even evaluated if f is null?

I know this works in VS current version, but what I need to know is if this is allowed by the C++ standard (or if it's UB).
Also, if I write it as 2 separate if to make it more readable, can I expect the compiler to optimize it into a single if?

```
struct foo 
{
   bool bar;
};

void main(){
   foo *f;
   // DO THINGS 
   if (f != null && f->bar == true)
   {
      // DO THINGS
   }
}
```

Edit: the question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925479/if-argument-evaluation-order) because it's not obvious that it's simply a matter of order: the proof is I did not end on that SO answer when I googled my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["IF" argument evaluation order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925479/if-argument-evaluation-order) TL;DR it is correct, standard specifies that evaluation order is left to right

Comment: `"Also, if I write it as 2 separate if to make it more readable, can I expect the compiler to optimize it into a single if?"` -- This question does not make sense, as the instructions emitted by the compiler do not use `if` statements. You can be reasonably certain that the compiler will not care whether you use one or two `if` statements. It will likely produce the same code, provided that you have compiler optimizations enabled.

Comment: @pptaszni: partly yes, thanks. Andreas: you're right, I meant if my 2 if-s get compiled as 2 conditional jump or just 1... but you got it right, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *...is it allowed to check that a pointer is not null and (&&) to also check one of its members value in the same if statement?*

[It's perfectly valid, it is not UB](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.compound#expr.log.and), the expression is evaluated from left to right, if the left part of the expression evaluates to `false` the right part is not evaluated. This is usually called operator short circuit.

The rationale is that if the first part is `false`, there is no possibilty of the whole expression being `true`, `false && false` is `false`, `false && true` is also `false`.

> *...if I write it as 2 separate if to make it more readable, can I expect the compiler to optimize it into a single if?*

In light of the above answer, you wouldn't need two `if`s, I would argue that it will not make your code more readable, I prefer the way you have it right know, in any case this is only my opinion. About the compiler, I wouldn't think that there will be much difference either way, as sampled in this [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yr6Mo1rfh).

Answer (score 1):

> is it allowed to check that a pointer is not null and (&&) to also check one of its members value in the same if statement?

Yes.

> is the right part of the condition in the example below even evaluated if f is null?

No.

> what I need to know is if this is allowed by the C++ standard

Yes.

> (or if it's UB)

No.

> Also, if I write it as 2 separate if to make it more readable, can I expect the compiler to optimize it into a single if?

I would expect it. Seems like a trivial optimisation. Note that in cases where the `&&` operator is overloaded (which never is in the case of pointers), such change can change the meaning of the program.

---

Standard quote (latest draft):

> [expr.log.and]
>
> The && operator groups left-to-right.
> The operands are both contextually converted to bool.
> The result is true if both operands are true and false otherwise.
> Unlike &, && guarantees left-to-right evaluation: **the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is false**.